# Extending Styled Component with Custom component works but the parent doesnt render the styles in Typescript? Not sure if Typescript is the issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have this code but doesnt work, it ignores all the styles in `BackgroundImage` except the one inside CustomBgImage. Im not sure if its a configuration, it does work in a different proyect. The difference between this and the other proyect is the way it was initialized; one was made with `npx create-react-app` and the other one with `npx create-react-app --template typescript`.

```
import { Container } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import CustomBgImage from "../custom-bg-image/custom-bg-image.component";

export const BackgroundImage = styled(CustomBgImage)`
  height: 100% !important;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;

  ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.up("lg")} {
    img {
      object-position: 0 -7rem;
    }
  }

  ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.down("md")} {
    height: 400px;
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
  }

  img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.down("md")} {
      height: 400px;
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: What's the version of MUI in both the projects?

Comment: @0xts Ok, so the version is "@mui/material": "^5.14.6" and I see a problem. In the regular reactjs project with no typescript I hover with the mouse in BackgroundImage and I see the CustomBgImage shown as an object type while in the typescript reactjs proyect I see a CustomBgImage instead of object. How can I fix this?